# How can I order my query results dynamically in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, dynamic

```
SELECT   Tbl.*,
          ROWNUM RN1
        FROM
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT( LEAVEID ),
                LEAVECODE,
                LEAVENAME,
                DESCRIPTION,
                STATUS
             FROM HRM_LEAVECONFIGURATION
              WHERE
                (
                  (
                    :LEAVENAME IS NULL OR
                    UPPER( LEAVENAME ) LIKE UPPER( :LEAVENAME )
                  )
                  AND
                  (
                    :STATUS IS NULL OR
                    STATUS   = :STATUS
                  )
                  AND
                  (
                    ISFIXED <> 1 OR
                    ISFIXED IS NULL
                  )
                  AND
                  (
                    :LEVECODE         IS NULL OR
                    UPPER( LEAVECODE ) = UPPER( :LEVECODE )
                  )
                )
              ORDER BY(
                  CASE
                      (
                        SELECT   t.data_type
                          FROM user_tab_columns t
                          WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'HRM_LEAVECONFIGURATION' AND
                            t.COLUMN_NAME    = 'LEAVENAME'
                      )
                    WHEN 'VARCHAR2'
                    THEN 'UPPER(LEAVENAME)'
                    ELSE 'LEAVENAME'
                  END ) DESC
          )
          Tbl
```

This is the code I am having problem.

Here I am passing a field name as parameter, according to the data type of the field I want give uppercase function.

e.g.,If I give leavename as the column to be ordered, if the datatype of leavename is varchar2 then order by upper(leavename) Descending,  if datatype of leavename is other than varchar then order by just leavename.

Here my problem is this query is working but it it s not getting ordered. Is there any other suggestion ?

Comment: add the same stuff you're using in `order by` part to `select` part so you can see what actual values were found.

Comment: You might also chose to use dynamic SQL because of the  [performance problems with the IS NULL OR appraoch](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic). In that case you might also be able to decide upon you ORDER BY clause in the app as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure under what circumstances the *datatype* of a column will vary.  Surely LEAVENAME is always going to be a VARCHAR2?

So all you need is this:

```
  ORDER BY(
  CASE
      when :LEAVENAME is not null THEN UPPER(LEAVENAME)
    ELSE LEAVENAME
  END ) DESC
```

Perhaps your precise business logic is different and you want to order by whatever columns for which you actually pass values.  In which case you should write something like this:

```
  ORDER BY(
  CASE
      when :LEAVENAME is not null THEN UPPER(LEAVENAME)
      when :LEVECODE is not null THEN UPPER(LEVECODE)
    ELSE LEAVENAME
  END ) DESC
```

Incidentally, you need to be careful with such queries.  They confuse the optimizer, which means they may perform poorly some or indeed all of the time.  Assembling a query dynamically is often a better approach.

Comment: But my need is little bit different.                              ORDER BY(
                  CASE
                      (
                        SELECT   t.data_type
                          FROM user_tab_columns t
                          WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'HRM_LEAVECONFIGURATION' AND
                            t.COLUMN_NAME    = 'LEAVENAME'
                      )
                    WHEN 'VARCHAR2'
                    THEN 'UPPER(LEAVENAME)'
                    ELSE 'LEAVENAME'
                  END ) DESC

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, you can't bind column names.

The order by belongs one layer out.   You are sorting the result set that you are selecting from, but not the final set.  The order by belongs after the final Tbl at the end of the query.